# Fetch related ID's and aggregate in a new column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, aggregate-functions

So my problem is coming from a poor understanding of the complexity of my query. A bit of a background story to this ask.

It's a car rental and search website, which started as a personal project of mine. I am using Django 2.1 for this, as well as Postgres.

The setup is as follows: I have a car model, which has an ID, a category, a car type, an engine etc. Secondly, there is an address table, that I use for all sorts of things.

What I would like to do now is the following:

I want to create Google Ads specific .csv files. This file needs a specific column with aggregated integers, in order to show 'related content' for the user. Meaning: You have seen Car A, here is a selection of related or similar cars in that area: Car K, O and Q.

I don't really have a problem making a csv from my data, but my problem is rather in constructing the query for this to work. I have the following as a first step:

```
cars = Car.objects
   .select_all_related()
   .only(
      'id',
      'name',
      'address__city',
      'address__city_area',
      'images'
  )
```

## 1

`select_all_related` joins the address table, because that's where the car is located. It also makes my only() call work, since I want to pull out specific fields

[Select Related Doc Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

## 2

only gives me only the fields I want, since I don't want to sent the whole model anyway, this also works.

[Only Doc Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)

So selecting and getting the correct data is not the problem, but:

The real problem:

The following code should create a column in the table. This column should have aggregated IDs of the cars that are in a similar area (city, and city area). And this is sadly a requirement by the Google Ads thing I use.

```
def find_similiar_cars_in_same_city(cars: QuerySet):
    """Annotate the QuerySet with a field called similar_cars_ids containing
       a list of ad IDs or None if there are none."""
    similar_cars_queryset = Cars.objects.filter(
            address__city=OuterRef('address__city'),
            address__city_area=OuterRef('address__city_area'),
              ).exclude(id=OuterRef('id')).values_list(ArrayAgg('id'), flat=True)
    # Hack: Remove GROUP BY that Django adds when adding ArrayAgg.
    similar_cars_queryset.query.group_by = []

    cars = cars.annotate(similar_cars_ids=Subquery(
        similar_cars_queryset,
        output_field=ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
    ))
    return cars
```

And this kinda works. just takes forever. You also can see the comment I made in the code, that annotate() actually groups by which I don't really want here. I run everything locally and even just having 10 cars takes about 12 seconds. I'm unsure if im missing anything. It kinda works, but wont work for larger sample size. I ran it against a DB with roughly 14k cars and it just never finished.

So to summarize: I want to make a function that creates a column in the db with aggregated IDs of similar cars.

Anyone has a pointer on where to make this more efficient? And please ask if there are any more questions and I forgot to mention something!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're paginating over the results, it might be easier to handle it in python.

```
cars = Car.objects
       .select_all_related()
       .only(
          'id',
          'name',
          'address__city',
          'address__city_area',
          'images'
      )

cars_in_area_map = defaultdict(set)
for car in cars:
    cars_in_area_map[(car.address.city, car.address.city_area)].add(car.id)

# Generate csv:
data = [
    car.id,
    car.name,
    car.address.city,
    car.address.city_area,
    car.image,
    {id for id in cars_in_area_map[(car.address.city, car.address.city_area)] if id != car.id},
]
```

If you need to paginate over them, you could try doing it via address:

```
data = []

addresses = Address.objects.prefetch_related('car_set')
for address in addresses:
    cars = list(address.car_set.all())
    for car in cars:
        data.append([
            car.id,
            car.name,
            address.city,
            address.city_area,
            car.image,
            {c.id for c in cars if c.id != c},
        ])
```

Comment: Yeah, paginating is kinda the goal later on.. :(

Comment: Added another option for you.